# How to get current date and time like this format 3:31 pm 7 July 2016

Tags: javascript, date, time, format

i am getting the current date and time like hh:mm am/pm dd month yyyy

i am getting dd month yyyy formate any one please help me.

```js
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDate();
var x = d.toDateString().substr(4,3);
var year = d.getFullYear();
document.querySelector("#mydate").innerHTML = day+' '+x+'    '+year;
```

```html
<div id="mydate"></div>
```

Comment: You can use moment.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check manually if the hour already pass 12 or not. If not, then use `AM`, if yes then use `PM`.

Then, you may want to add `0` in front of the minute and hour if they are less than 10.

```
var dateResult = formatDate();
document.querySelector("#mydate").innerHTML = dateResult;

function formatDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var x = d.toDateString().substr(4,3);
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var minute = padZero(d.getMinutes());
    var AMPM = "AM";

    var checkHour = parseInt(hour);

    if (checkHour > 12) {
        AMPM = "PM";
        hour = checkHour - 12;
    }
    else if (checkHour === 0) {
        hour = "12";
    }

    hour = padZero(hour);

    return hour + ':' + minute + " " + AMPM + " " + day+' '+x+'    '+year;
}

function padZero(value) {
    return (value < 10) ? "0" + value : value;
}
```

You could test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8mywzwrv/).